# MRB_THROW causes error in libc++abi.dylib

Tags: c++, ios, dylib, mruby

I'm trying to build a modified version of [ios-ruby-embedded](https://github.com/carsonmcdonald/ios-ruby-embedded) project with some extra gems, including the [mruby-marshal](https://github.com/take-cheeze/mruby-marshal) gem from the [mruby-mgems](https://github.com/mruby/mgem-list) list (which includes a .cpp file). I can get it to build and run, but if I raise any exception the app crashes when it calls `MRB_THROW` from error.c with the following message:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type int
```

I suspect the problem is a conflict in how mRuby exception handling is being compiled and linked: according to the documentation, it can use either setjmp/longjmp handling or C++ exceptions if C++ code is included; however, I can't figure out what combination of configuration options I need to get it to work.

In order to get it to build I made some changes to the project:

- Add the conf.cxx sections for each target in the Rakefile (duplicating the settings in the conf.cc sections)
- Add the '-lc++' flag to 'Other Linker Flags' in the Xcode project I'm using (derived from the [mruby-ios-example](https://github.com/carsonmcdonald/MRubyiOSExample) project)
- In the mruby-marshal project, use the [mruby-pure-regexp](https://github.com/mruby/mgem-list/blob/master/mruby-pure-regexp.gem) gem instead of the [mruby-onig-regexp](https://github.com/mruby/mgem-list/blob/master/mruby-onig-regexp.gem) dependency

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the `-fexceptions` flag to the C compiler flags list. I prepared a [gist](https://gist.github.com/WaveformDelta/a41d70d3a715c6735806b4d7f2c07fb2) with the Rakefile I used to fix this, note the `conf.cc` flags.